# How to determine the package that defines a particular identifier?

Tags: r

When reading source code written by others, it is often difficult for me to figure out what package a particular identifier (typically a function) comes from.  (This is because such code "imports" identifiers through statements of the form `library(...)`, which enables the use in the code of the imported identifiers without having to provide a package qualifier.)

Is there a simple way to determine the package a particular identifier comes from?

Comment: If you print the function definition in R, it should say from which namespace it comes from. Is this sufficient information for you?

Comment: ?functionname and on the top left in the help page. Also, Gabor Csardi showed in his useR2016 talk that he interlinked a lot of the browsable code at http://r-pkg.org (metacran) automatically. (I have not tried this myself).

Comment: `getAnywhere('lm')$where` is a non manual R solution returning a list with the package and namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function `getAnywhere()`. Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
getAnywhere("%>%")$where
```

This tells you both the package and the namespace:

```
[1] "package:dplyr"      "namespace:magrittr"
```